# Moneris Payment Processor - use CIviCRM Invoice ID as Order ID in Moneris

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor

For simple reconciliation, our client is requesting that the CiviCRM Invoice # be passed to Moneris as the Order ID for more straight-forward reconciliation.

We are referring to the default INV_xxxxx Invoice ID that CiviCRM generates.

Right now, Moneris passes back a random hash (ie, 0xf99c700c82a2e0011d750b925fd2db).

We currently use the modified Moneris plugin as provided by adixon @ Blackfly - https://github.com/adixon/ca.civicrm.moneris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a good idea, most payment processors don't really like those 'random hash' things. But that random hash is the "invoice_id", and it's just how civicrm generates it (for good reasons, actually). The "Invoice ID" you describe is an optional piece of 4.6, so not always available. Also, I'm not sure if it's available to the payment processor plugin. Anyone else have an idea?